# SOQL Query not bringing back parent with no comments

Tags: soap, salesforce, soql, salesforce-chatter

Due to the way this is structured I can't bring back groups with no comments/feeds in them, unfortunately trying to invert this brings up multiple errors as `CollaborationGroup` does not understand the relationship it has with `CollaborationGroupFeed`.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
        c.Parent.Id, 
        c.Parent.OwnerId, 
        c.Parent.CreatedById, 
        c.Id, 
        c.ParentId, 
        (
          SELECT 
                  Id, 
                  FeedItemId, 
                  ParentId
          FROM FeedComments
        )

FROM CollaborationGroupFeed c
```

I can't do it like this though for whatever reason:

```
SELECT 
        Id, 
        OwnerId, 
        CreatedById, 
        (
          SELECT 
                  Id, 
                  ParentId
          FROM CollaborationGroupFeeds
        ),
        (
          SELECT 
                  Id, 
                  FeedItemId, 
                  ParentId
          FROM FeedComments
        )

FROM CollaborationGroup
```

> Didn't understand relationship 'CollaborationGroupFeed' in FROM part of query call.`

**EDIT**

So lets say I have a Group that I just created called Foo

```
[FOO]
```

Foo has one Post in it `BlahPost`

```
[FOO]
|
|_BlahPost
```

Lets say `BlahPost` has a comment (or several)

```
[FOO]
|
|_BlahPost
        |_Comment 1
        |_Comment 2
```

The query above will return all of this.

Now lets say I have a new Group Bar

```
[Bar]
```

Since there are NO posts/comments  the query above returns nothing since I'm working from child to parent,
and parent has no posts. I am looking for a query that starts at the parent `CollaborationGroup` and moves
down to `CollaborationFeed` which will display `FeedComment`

Make more sense? The order is mess up, I'm working from the middle and should be working from the top

Comment: what's your question specifically?

Comment: I'm looking to query CollaborationGroup, and also return the CollaborationGroupFeed subquery along with the FeedComments sub-subquery. Right now, its child to parent, so CollaborationGroupFeed does not display CollaborationGroup items that don't already have comments in them. Let me write up a little map really quick so you can see

Comment: @downvoter, if you are going to downvote, please leave a comment why, not just a negative mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Chatter in Apex, which is Chatter REST API resource actions exposed as static methods in the Apex ConnectApi namespace. It's a much easier way to access Chatter data.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/connectAPI_overview.htm

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm